# ComboBox that remembers recently entered values and can autocomplete

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autocomplete

I'm developing a Desktop Search Engine in VB.NET
I'm using a ComboBox to specify the search query (string).
I want the ComboBox to remember and display recent queries.
I also want the ComboBox to try and Autocomplete the queries as the user is typing.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: ComboBox?? I cant see how that will work... I can picture it with a Textbox

Answer (score 1):

This can no doubt be done more elegantly, but here's the basic principles (apologies for any syntax issues, I'm not much of a VB guy):

In the KeyUp event:

1. Make sure the key in't a navigation key:

   ```
   if e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back [...]
   ```
2. Search the items list for the text typed:

   ```
   idx = myCombo.FindString(myCombo.Text)
   ```
3. Take the combo's found item:

   ```
   s = myCombo.GetItemText(idx)
   ```
4. insert it into the .Text property:

   ```
   myCombo.Text = s
   ```

Note that this would overtype everything the user entered (destroying case).  You could improve this by appending the 'missing' part instead:

```
stringToAppend = s.SubString(myCombo.Text.Length)
myCombo.Text = myCombo.Text + stringToAppend
```

Finally, select the new text so they can keep typing:

```
myCombo.SelectionStart = myCombo.Text.Length - stringToAppend.Length
myCombo.SelectionLength = stringToAppend.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/Code/Controls/ListBox_and_ComboBox/Reusing_the_Combo_Dropdown/article.asp) from vbAccelerator.com, offered as a basic starting point for auto-completion in VB.NET. The vbAccelerator code is usually high quality.